# What makes a (too large) neural network diverge?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, neural-network, backpropagation

I've build a neural network (NN) having only 6 inputs and 8 classes (it is thus a classifier I'm building).

To give some more background:
The number of training samples is 80,000 samples as is the dev/cross-validation set size (I know this is not a good split, but to compare my outputs to those of my colleague, I have to keep the train/dev sets as is). The input features are following relatively well defined probability density functions, albeit not Gaussian.

Due to the large number of inputs relative to the number of features, the data set is 'practically impossible' to overfit, and I have not yet succeeded in doing this (even with very large networks). This is intuitively correct since the feature pdf's are overlapping and dense enough to prevent *curve loops* to gather more and more samples.

Now, since I like to test the limits of algo's and thus also my NN, I've ran a week-long monte-carlo session varying all parameters, including the number of layers and the number of nodes per layer as hyperparameters.

I've noticed that in many cases (when the number of layers and nodes per layer are large enough) the NN converges after some time (let's say 300+ interations), then levels out, but after a few hundred iterations more, it starts to diverge and become unstable (non-smooth and showing large jumps).

I know from basic NN theory that for the case I'm describing (6 inputs, 8 classes) a single hidden layer with around 10 nodes should suffice (and it does by the way), but I would expect a NN having more layers and having more nodes per layer to at least **not diverge** and stay approximately around the minimum.

Especially, since when the gradient is zero, the step size must become by definition zero, right? or am I missing something?

Now my question is twofold:

1. **Is there some theory on how one can predict when a NN will diverge?** 
   Since I'm going to try my hand at a problem more suitable to solve via a (convolutional) NN, I would like to at least have some insight in this matter.
2. **How is it possible that a NN diverges?** Note that due to the fact that I've used *gradient checking* to check my backprop and the fact that smaller NNs do not diverge, I've got confidence in my NN (even though I did use only numpy/python and no automatic-backprop frameworks like Keras/TensorFlow).

   2.1 I've got a feeling this is a numerical implementation *thingy* however, even in this case, how would I be able to prevent this? Any info, tips, tricks would be highly appreciated.

   2.2 my case is quite different from most (computer vision) cases (*cat classifiers* and such) and thus the small number of features/inputs is probably a factor too. In the computer vision networks, the number of features is way higher than the number of nodes, very much unlike my simple case.

Kind regards and thanks in advance for any feedback.

My optimizer is ADAM optimization, which I've implemented in numpy:

```
def update_with_adam(W, b, dW, db, v_dW, v_db, s_dW, s_db, alpha, istep, beta_v=0.9, beta_s=0.999):
  """
  Update the parameters using ADAM optimization
  """
  eps = 1e-8
  nof_layers = len(W)

  for l in range(1, nof_layers):

    # Momentum
    v_dW[l] = beta_v*v_dW[l] + (1 - beta_v)*dW[l]
    v_db[l] = beta_v*v_db[l] + (1 - beta_v)*db[l]

    # rmsprop
    s_dW[l] = beta_s*s_dW[l] + (1 - beta_s)*(dW[l]**2)
    s_db[l] = beta_s*s_db[l] + (1 - beta_s)*(db[l]**2)

    # initialization corrections
    v_dW_corr = v_dW[l]/(1 - beta_v**(istep + 1))
    v_db_corr = v_db[l]/(1 - beta_v**(istep + 1))

    s_dW_corr = s_dW[l]/(1 - beta_s**(istep + 1))
    s_db_corr = s_db[l]/(1 - beta_s**(istep + 1))

    # delta modifiers
    dW_mod = v_dW_corr/(np.sqrt(s_dW_corr) + eps)
    db_mod = v_db_corr/(np.sqrt(s_db_corr) + eps)

    # update step
    W[l] = W[l] - alpha*dW_mod
    b[l] = b[l] - alpha*db_mod

  return W, b, v_dW, v_db, s_dW, s_db
```

Note that all parameters (W, b, v_dW and such) are lists in which W[l] are the weights for layer l (with l=0 is the input layer)

Comment: Please specify what you mean exactly with diverging. Is the val loss diverging or also the training loss? Feed Forward NN tend to behave difficult for many hidden layers. First you hav your classical overtraining problem because of too many parameters to train. You can counter this with regularizations methods like Dropout. Also there is a vanishing gradient problem with deep structures. There are many possible solutions. E.g. the selu activation function is said to regularize many hiddden layers well. Also stacking many ff layers is rarely the best topology to build your net.

Comment: Are you monitoring cost and accuracy from the dataset used for training or do you have a seperate validation dataset to monitor on?

Comment: In the question I've given more info: Overfitting is not the problem (80000 training samples vs 6 features/8 classes and dense pdfs, plus the fact that the dev and training costs are almost overlaying)

Comment: @dennis-ec: I've indeed a separate training and dev set (or cv set is you prefer). The 50/50 split is unlucky, but I've been given this data from a colleague and to be able to compare confusion matrices, I cannot tinker with this split ratio

Comment: Thanks for the update. Since you seem to implement your network only with python/numpy, is it possible for you to post your code? It would be easier to see if you implement something different then those frameworks. My next guess would be that your Optimizer is the problem. Which one did you implement?

Comment: @dennis-ec: Well, since I work in radar industry, showing code is .. uhm.. tricky... However, give me some time, and I'll edit the question to include - relevant - code .. Hopefully tomorrow...

Comment: Thanks I know that is sometimes very difficult to share your code. One approach, which could be easier: Try to rebuild your NN using tf with/without keras and see if the behaviour still occurs.

Comment: I've pasted my generic optimizer code. Maybe you find a problem (I hope so). However, what you're proposing is what I'll do next (as soon as keras will be installed correctly by the ICT department). However, I'm not sure that the behaviour I get is not linked to some property of the deep NNs instead of being a mistake